# How enable_dl configuration in php can be useful?

Tags: php, apache, configuration

I was going through php.ini and I have found the following parameter [enable_dl](http://www.php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.enable-dl) with a strange description:

> This directive is really only useful in the Apache module version of
>   PHP. You can turn dynamic loading of PHP extensions with dl() on and
>   off per virtual server or per directory.
>
> The main reason for turning dynamic loading off is security. With
>   dynamic loading, it's possible to ignore all open_basedir
>   restrictions. The default is to allow dynamic loading, except when
>   using safe mode. In safe mode, it's always impossible to use dl().

I am running php on apache and I am curious how exactly this parameter can be useful for me. Above-mentioned description is not really clear to me, so I would be thankful if someone can elaborate it.

Comment: As much as it is about wondering, I'm curious, too, how exactly this parameter can be useful for you. Why don't you share?

Comment: @hakre sorry, I did not get your comment. I will try to rephrase my question. I saw this parameter, I read documentation about it but still have no clue what it does. Can someone explain to me what does it do?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

PHP modules (extensions) can only be loaded in the startup-phase of PHP. For example it is not possible to load them with [`.user.ini` files](http://php.net/configuration.file.per-user). The [`extension` directive](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.extension) for example is *php.ini only*.

This is a hint - historically `.user.ini` files were not in core, but per-directory .htaccess settings for the SAPI for Apache mod_php.

To circumvent this restriction in the past, the `dl()` function had been introduced to dynamically load extensions at run-time. However only if enabled, so the `enable_dl` directive.

However support for `dl` has been largely disabled in current PHP SAPIs, having it available *only* in  CLI and Embed.

As you haven't been said why you're curious about `dl()` the best answer I can give, is that it is useful for esoteric reasons only. Most likely it's even useless with the SAPI you want to use it with (you have not shared the SAPI name, but I guess it's not CLI nor Embed).

Comment: Thanks for explanation. I have no idea what it does and can it be helpful for me. Right now I see I see that there is no point to change it in my config files.

Comment: @Salvador Dali: Rule of thumb: If you see no helpfulness, you most likely do not need it. Shed away the waste, many PHP features are there for historical reasons, ensure you're good with the system administration and tell them your requirements.

Comment: Thank you for help, it was just a curiosity. I saw parameter, was not able to understand it and thus asked for help.

Comment: @SalvadorDali: SO is not so good with out of curiosity questions, because no-one else can actually imagine what you're looking for. Better tell what you're wondering about exactly, e.g. which part you don't understand.

Comment: enable_dl = On       add this in php.ini it will enable it (@hakre 's explanation is valuable)

Answer (score 0):

this is old but i will answer this.
https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.dl.php says all you need to know. Basically when you define extensions to load in your php ini file below, this allows the same thing but on a code level. It is however faster to preload than to use this so unless you specifically load extensions in code, it is better to keep this disabled.